# Unable to stop DispatchQueue.global().async task on swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dispatch-async

I am running a infinite loop to vibrate my phone inside dispatchQueue.global().async task so my UI doesn't get freeze, but the problem is I  have been unable to stop it. below is my code

```
var queue: DispatchWorkItem?

queue = DispatchWorkItem {
            while (self.l > 1)
            {
                AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
            }
        }

        DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: queue!)
```

And below is the code where I am trying to stop it when the users leaves the screen

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        queue?.cancel()
        l=0
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            self.queue?.cancel()
        }
        print("view will disapear")
    }
```

Tried almost everything, but still failed to stop the global dispatch task.
PS: I am new to iOS development :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue has been resolved, actually should't have used dispatch global async in first place. Tried doing it with a timer and it worked, vibrating after each secs and it doesn't freeze the UI, also gets stopped easily after just calling timer.invalidate(). Thanks for the help guys :)

Answer (score 1):

`GCD`(Grand Central Dispatch) Queues cannot be stopped. If you want to stop the async queues then you have to use `NSOperationQueue` which has option to `pause`, `resume`, `cancel` the task in queue.

From your code, you can try one more thing to stop it, as you are using infinite loop to vibrate. Here in loop, you can add some condition to not vibrate further.

Comment: I tried to stop it via changing condition if you see on viewWillDisappear, I am changing the value of l = 0, so the while condition becomes false, but still id didn't work. Okay, I will look into NSOperationQueue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `var queue: DispatchWorkItem?` is a `DispatchWorkItem` and can be canceled if not yet executed. So if you make sure `DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: queue!)` call after `viewWillDisappear` your code should work as expected.

Comment: Calling DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: queue!) inside viewWilldisappear function won't start the vibration func in first place, if that's what you mean, correct me if I am wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: What I trying to say is about the time mate. if you call `DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: queue!)` before `self.queue?.cancel()`. `queue` cannot be canceled. If after, can. Hope this makes it clear mate.

Comment: Thanks, but had to go with different approach and it worked :)